# Using awk on Nmap ssl-enum-cipher results

Tags: ssl, awk, text, tls1.2, nmap

I'm creating a bash script that loops through a collection of IP-addresses and scans them with the Nmap ssl-enum-ciphers script. Everything works just fine except for one feature.

I need to find a way how I can link the scanned port with the TLS versions & ciphers found.

The Nmap data looks like this ->

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE    VERSION
21/tcp   open  ftp        vsftpd 3.0.2
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.0: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - F
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - F
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - F
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - F
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - F
|       TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - F
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 4096) - A
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|     warnings: 
|       Anonymous key exchange, score capped at F
|       Key exchange (dh 1024) of lower strength than certificate key
|       Key exchange (secp256r1) of lower strength than certificate key
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - F
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (dh 1024) - F
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (dh 1024) - F
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - F
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (dh 1024) - F
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (dh 1024) - F
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - F
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - F
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - F
|       TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - F
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 4096) - A
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|     warnings: 
|       Anonymous key exchange, score capped at F
|       Key exchange (dh 1024) of lower strength than certificate key
|       Key exchange (secp256r1) of lower strength than certificate key
|_  least strength: F
22/tcp   open  ssh        OpenSSH 7.4 (protocol 2.0)
80/tcp   open  http       nginx
443/tcp  open  ssl/http   nginx
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|_  least strength: A
```

I need to format this data in something like this ->

```
21/tcp   open  ftp        vsftpd 3.0.2
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.0: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - F
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - F
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - F
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - F
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - F
|       TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - F
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 4096) - A
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - F
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (dh 1024) - F
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (dh 1024) - F
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - F
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (dh 1024) - F
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (dh 1024) - F
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - F
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - F
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - F
|       TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - F
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 4096) - A
443/tcp  open  ssl/http   nginx
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
```

I've managed to create a awk script that collects all the open ports with status and versions running ->

```
    #!/usr/bin/awk -f
    
    /open/ {
        port = $1
        state = $2
        service = $3
    }
    /ssl-enum-ciphers/ {
        print port, state, service
    }
```

outputs ->

```
21/tcp open ftp
443/tcp open ssl/http
```

As you can see the only things that are missing are the found TLS versions + ciphers.
Can someone give me a push in the right direction?

Thanks in advance,

Sleek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a reduced dataset:

```
$ cat nmap.dat
PORT     STATE SERVICE    VERSION
21/tcp   open  ftp        vsftpd 3.0.2
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.0:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|     warnings:
|       Anonymous key exchange, score capped at F
|       Key exchange (dh 1024) of lower strength than certificate key
|   TLSv1.2:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (dh 1024) - A
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|     warnings:
|       Anonymous key exchange, score capped at F
|       Key exchange (dh 1024) of lower strength than certificate key
|_  least strength: F
22/tcp   open  ssh        OpenSSH 7.4 (protocol 2.0)
80/tcp   open  http       nginx
443/tcp  open  ssl/http   nginx
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.2:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|_  least strength: A
```

General approach is to use a flag (`printme`) to determine when to print a line; comparisons will determine when to turn on (`1`) or off (`0`) the flag.

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
/open/               { port = $1
                       state = $2
                       service = $3
                     }
/ssl-enum-ciphers/   { print port, state, service
                       printme=1
                     }
/compressors:/       { printme=0 }
/cipher preference:/ { printme=0 }
/warnings:/          { printme=0 }
/TLS.*:/             { printme=1 }
printme
' nmap.dat
```

**NOTES:**

- assumes all cipher subsections (under `ssl-enum-ciphers`) of interest are of the form `TLS*:`; otherwise OP can add more patterns for enabling the print flag (`printme=1`)
- based solely on the provided sample input a single test for `/compressors:/` should be sufficient to clear the print flag (`printme=0`); I'm not familiar with all possible `nmap` output formats so I've gone ahead and added the `/cipher preference:/` and `/warnings:/` tests, too; these last two tests can be removed if OP determines `/compressors:/` is sufficient for clearing the print flag

This generates:

```
21/tcp open ftp
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.0:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
|   TLSv1.2:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (dh 1024) - A
443/tcp open ssl/http
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.2:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
```